# SQL - Getting value from another table

Tags: sql-server

Object Resource Table :

```
ObjectID|Resource

01     | Resource A
01     | Resource B
```

Object Availability Table :

```
AvailID|DayName

01     | Monday
02     | Tuesday
```

ObjectResourceAvailability Table :

```
ObjectID|Resource Name|Day

01      |ResourceA    | 01
```

Ideally it should show

```
ObjectID|Resource Name|DayName

01      |ResourceA, ResourceB    | Monday, Tuesday
```

I've also concatenated columns having the same ID.
How can I make the end result showing Monday instead of 01 instead? I've tried selecting ObjAvail.DayName and changing the concatenating strings solution but i kept getting column invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is the solution that's helped me achieve concatenating columns

```
  SELECT
        t1.oid
            ,STUFF(
                       (SELECT
                            ', ' + t2.resource
                            FROM objectresource t2
                            WHERE t1.oid=t2.oid
                            ORDER BY t2.resource
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                       ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                       ,1,2, ''
                  ) AS Resources
                  ,STUFF(
    (
        SELECT
            ',',
            CAST(availyid AS VARCHAR)
        FROM objectAvail t2
        WHERE t1.oid = t2.oId
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') as [Days]
        FROM objectresource t1
        GROUP BY t1.oid
```

Comment: dont tag your question with two db. mysql and sql-server?

Comment: Your second STUFF / FOR XML PATH doesn't is not picking up the DayName column from the Object Availability Table.

    SELECT ',',CAST(availyid AS VARCHAR)

should be 

SELECT ',' + Dayname

Comment: firstly, make you monday is set as the first day of the week (please see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) and then I would write a case statement depending on the number returned to output the day of the week

Comment: @SeanR I'm not able to do that because Dayname is from another table. I've changed SELECT ',' + Dayname from ObjectAvail table and it gives me the same invalid error

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work (:

```
ObjId|Resource|Day
1    |RescA,RescB | Mon,Tue

SELECT
    v.ObjId,STUFF(
                   (SELECT
                        ', ' + t2.resource
                        FROM Objresc t2
                        WHERE v.Objid=t2.Objid
                        ORDER BY t2.resource
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                   ,1,2, ''
              ) AS 'Resources'
              , 
    STUFF(
    (SELECT
       ',' + DayName
     FROM avail m 
     INNER JOIN ObjAvail vm ON m.availid = vm.availid
     WHERE vm.ObjId = v.Objid
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS 'Days'
FROM ObjResc v
group by v.Objid
```